# what to do about rust on 2014 civic

Tags: honda, civic, rust

so i have a 2014 civic that got its paint scraped off after i turned a corner too sharply in a parking garage about a year and a half ago... and about a year ago i had a guy fix it. i didnt notice at the time but he had somehow scraped off some paint on the inside back rear door jamb at about waist height, leaving bare metal. its about 0.5 cm by about 4 cm lengthwise and has begun to rust. i took it to an autobody shop and the guy was adamrnt that its not worth fixing.

"scrape the rust off with your nail and paint over it with a little artists brush" he said.

should i be worried about it? i heard rust can spread quickly.

thanks

Comment: I agree with the guy who you advice that scrape the rust completely and paint it with brush. rear door jamb is not an important part of the chassis frame when it comes to driving, so if you don't mind the scratches (and looking) after painting, you can solve the problem in this way.

Answer (score 1):

First off give it some diagnostics, it's pretty easy to see the extent of rust damage. Take a screwdriver and poke at the rust spot at a medium strength as if you're trying to poke through thin cardboard. If it goes straight through the panel we have a bigger problem at hand.

If it doesn't take some 220 grit paper and sand down all the rust and surrounding paint to either the primer or the bare metal. Spray down some rust inhibiting primer and then follow up with a wet sand with high grit paper and then finish with some color matched paint. Labor shouldn't take more than an hour from prep to dry.

Best of luck in your endeavors!

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, if the rust has overflown this part of the bodywork, you should change the whole part, if you have the money for it. But the best way is, to scrape it off and before you paint over it, put a bit of fat or special oil on it. That is an old home remedy.